# If name main check in Nim

Tags: program-entry-point, nim-lang

So, If you know Python, you should be familiar with this:

```
def main():
    <your code>


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

That creates a main function and checks if current files is being run or imported. I would like to know if there is any way to do that in Nim.

Edit: Also, is it suggested to do it.

Comment: This question isn't really about Python (Python expertise is largely irrelevant to answering it), so I've removed the Python-related tags.

Answer (score 5):

In Nim there is `when isMainModule:` it's documented here: https://nim-lang.org/docs/tut1.html#modules

Comment: Is it suggested to do that though?

Answer (score 3):

Since Nim is compiled, such check is done at compile-time with `when` by checking [isMainModule](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#isMainModule)

```
proc main =
  echo "hi"

when isMainModule:
  main()
```

Here `main()` will only be called if you're compiling this file as the program entry point - it won't run if you're importing this file in another one.

Comment: Is it suggested to do that though?

Comment: @OrlandoHuang There's no "best practice" for this because it's mainly made for practical reasons - if you're developing a hybrid library+app (so that it can both be used as a standalone app and as a library), then this will be useful for you, but otherwise - no, there's no need to use it at all.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, whether to use `when isMainModule` is not very often discussed, and you can use it if you want.
It is not often used in apps, but if your app has a apparent entry point or main function, and you think that it can open a block for the entry point to make things clear, you can use it.
It is usually used for simple tests in libs; for complex tests, developers use `unittest` module.